# Change Ownership of Google Document in Shared Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I was trying to change the ownership of a file that is being created by other users to myself so they cannot make any changes afterwards but the file is on a shared drive and i got the Error that you could not do this operation for Shared Drive Files.

Is there any work-around for this?

Answer (score 1):

They have to transfer the property to you, you can not transfer the property unless you are the owner of the file.